# bootstrap modal highlight does not appear

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, highlight

My issue with Bootstrap modal is that when i click on the button that must open a modal, the model will open fine, but without highlight, means i can click anywhere, no matter where, its will instantly close itself and the content of the model is behind the "shadow". How to get the content Highlighted? I've using a similar plugin called Lightbox V2. Tried to disable it but its the same issue.

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn" >Regis</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>One fine body…</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `hide` class from the modal div:
`<div id="myModal" class="modal`<strike>`hide`</strike>`fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">`

Answer (score 1):

Does your content that is supposed to be displayed in the modal remains hidden under the darker overlay of the modal and you are not supposed to access that hidden content ? If this is your problem, then **I will suggest you to check that all your `<div>`s that are before the `<div>` of modal are correctly closed**, because I faced the same problem, and when I checked my code I found that I missed closing a  that is supposed to be completed before the modal's code section.